# oAuth2 protected APIs + Facebook

Tags: facebook, angularjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I know this question has already been asked by someone else, but I didn't found the answers to my exact question.

I'm building a backend that provides its API written using Django REST Framework and integrates Facebook using Django Social Auth.
The frontend consumes the API using AngularJS.
I used a simple Token-based Authentication and everything went well, when somebody authenticated with Facebook I could retrieve the simple token (which never expired) from the DB and return it to the frontend, which will use it for subsequent calls to the API.

My problem now is that I want to publish my APIs and use oAuth2.
In order to do this I am using Django OAuth Toolkit.

If a user uses the native login there is no problem, because I use `resource owner password based grant type` (giving only client_id because the frontend is a JS app).
Now, if a user authenticates using Facebook there is a problem! I have no password to use!

This fact made me reconsider everything about authentication in my backend.
I thought this:
Is it sensed to make my "official" frontend app consume the APIs using oAuth2?
Isn't it better to use Token-based authentication (or Session-based, if you prefer) only for my frontend app and let third party apps consume APIs using oAuth2?
And, if I do like this, how can I tell my "official" app from other apps? Wouldn't it become a leak in security (for some reason, I don't know...)